# How to access the value of a listbox on another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, vs-web-site-project

I have a website in c#, in the first page I have some listbox, I need that
the last user's choice goes to a label in other page, how can I do that?

In my code if
the user chooses a value a button is visible, and in the click event of that button
redirect to to another page, but I need that value in a label in the page2

```
if (ddlFunciones.SelectedValue.Equals("15"))
{
    lblAgregarNuevoServicio.Visible = true;
    //lblIdFuncion.Visible = true;
    lblDescripcion.Visible = true;
    //txtId_funcion.Visible = true;
    txtDescripcionFuncion.Visible = true;
    btnAgregarNuevaFuncion.Visible = true;
}


protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnVerCargos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btnVerCargos.Enabled)
    {
        ListBoxCargo.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ListBoxCargo.Visible = false;
    }
}
protected void ListBoxCargo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is in Asp.Net you can pass information between pages in a number of ways.
You can use the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) object

```
protected void ListBoxCargo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Session["MyVar"] = ListBoxCargo.SelectedValue;
}
```

and in your other page

```
object value;
if (Session["MyVar"] != null)
{
   value = Session["MyVar"]
}
```

**OR**

By passing them in the QueryString see [Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString)
And using `Request.QueryString["MyVar"]`

and of course there are more, please explain what exactly are you trying to do...

**Edit: Based on OPs comments:**

In page1:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Page1Value"] = ListBox3.SelectedItem.Text;
       //Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx");
    }
```

In Page2:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (Session["Page1Value"] != null)
    {
       Label1.Text = Session["Page1Value"].ToString();
    }
 }
```

Comment: In the first page there are a lots of listbox (6) if the user in the page1 choose the first value in the first listbox goes to the 2nd listbox, if choose the first value in the 2nd listbox the button apears and re direct the user to page 2 but I need that last choice apears as a label in the page 2, thanks.

Comment: What is the name of your 2nd listbox?

Comment: the 2nd listbox is listbox2828, if user choose 1st value goes to listbox2830, then the button gets visible and redirect the user to de 2nd page, thanks

Comment: So you want to save the value of listbox2828 and pass it to page2? And you want this done when the button is pressed?

Comment: yes, I need that the user choose a value in the listbox1, dependes of that value goes to listbox2 or 3, if goes to lisbox2 and choose the 1st value, a button apears and if the user press that button goes to page2, I want in the page2 a label with the last seleccion of the user, thanks :)

Comment: @suely , what is considered the "last selection" ??

Comment: this is the app, a user goes to the lisbox1, if choose 1st value, goes to listbox2828, if in that lisbox choose the 1st value, goes to listbox2830, if choose the 1st value a button apears and redirect the user to page2, "last selecction" is the last value that the user choose, sorry I don´t speack english, maybe I didn't explaing very good my question, thanks in advance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13012/discussion-between-blachshma-and-suely)

Comment: as @Blachshma said, but the code: `Session["Page1Value"] = ListBox3.SelectedItem.Text;` is in the listbox3_SelectedIndexChanged event, not in the button

Answer (score 1):

Before you redirect the user to another page, store the selected value in the user's session.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Session["userSelectedValue"] = ListBox1.SelectedValue;
     Response.Redirect("OtherPage.aspx");
 }
```

On the other page just extract the selected value from the session.

For example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedValue = Session["userSelectedValue"];    
}
```

More than enough examples of working with session variables available on the interwebs.

I suggest you read up on [ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx).